# Where is $row defined?

Tags: php, mysql

In the code below, can someone tell me where the variable $row is coming from in the foreach statement?

```
public function getProcResultSet($cmd)
    {
         try
        {
            $meta = $cmd->result_metadata();

            while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
            {
                $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
            }

            call_user_func_array(array(
                $cmd,
                'bind_result'), $params);

            while ($cmd->fetch())
            {
                foreach ($row as $key => $val)
                {
                    $c[$key] = $val;
                }

                $results[] = $c;
            }

            return $results;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            logToFile("Exception: " . $e);
            return resultFailedUnknown();
        }
}
```

Edit, here is the caller of this function:

```
public static function getPlayerUnits($playerId, $unitTypeId)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(GDB_HOST, GDB_USERNAME, GDB_PASSWORD, GDB_NAME);

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            throw new Exception('DB Connection Failed. Error Code: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
        }

        $cmd = $mysqli->prepare('CALL sp_get_player_units(?, ?)');

        if (!$cmd)
        {
            throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
        }

        $cmd->bind_param('ii', $playerId, $unitTypeId);
        $cmd->execute();

        $results = parent::getProcResultSet($cmd);

        $cmd->close();
        $mysqli->close();

        return $results;
    }
```

Here is the result array which all I did was receive on a client and JSON.stringify(..):

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Machine Gunner","Quantity":0},{"Id":2,"Name":"Rocket Soldier","Quantity":0},{"Id":3,"Name":"Paratrooper","Quantity":0},{"Id":4,"Name":"Demolition Soldier","Quantity":0}]
```

As you can see, the result is showing the columns per row as expected.

Comment: Its not defined perhaps you mean while($row = $cmd->fetch)

Comment: Note to everyone: The line "$params[] = &$row[$field->name];" is what is defining the $row variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first `while` loop, because of the reference operator `&`. It doesn't exist before though.

The line `$params[] = &$row[$field->name]` creates the `$row` variable. What happens is that PHP wants to take a reference to `$row` that doesn't exist, so it creates it without any message (quite a bug source if you'd ask me). The `$row` is created as array with a key `$field->name` set to nothing.

`$row` **does** exist in the `foreach` loop, but not in the `while` loop. There it is created as an array with empty values.

The whole thing is quite obfuscated code and not very readable. Sometimes being verbose in code is a Good Thing.

Comment: I've confirmed that the line "$params[] = &$row[$field->name];" is creating the $row variable.

Comment: bah. I hate PHP :) please post an answer.

Comment: @MeshMan updated my answer, apparently, when using a reference operator, PHP silently creates the variable. I learned something today as well .. ;).

Comment: http://3v4l.org/ti9nj - seems to be consistent. the opcode format shows `FETCH_DIM_W`. there's a entry in the PHP manual for this, but it's ridiculous. oh well...

Comment: Also found a bug report from december 2000 where it says it should work like that: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=8085

Answer (score -1):

Normally people declare `$row` as the result of `mysql_fetch_row($result)`, where `$result` is what you get after querying your SQL database. However, I don't see that mentioned anywhere here so I don't think your code should actually work.

edit: obviously the exception to this would be if this isn't your entire file and it's defined somewhere above this. but yeah, shouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: by works perfectly I assume you meant "it doesn't do anything"

Comment: No, I mean the array that this produces is EXACTLY what I was expecting. The columns from the resulting query are perfectly set in the resulting array.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't believe that. There is no way this code works perfectly unless there is something you're not showing us.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the caller. I'll grab the resulting array for you in a second...

Comment: Maybe it's defined within `parent`. But yeah I still don't see this working.

Comment: Are you really sure that's the function that's being called? It's possible that it's being overridden somewhere else. (Add some `echo`s or something to confirm.)

Comment: I've added the resulting array which I got in JSON form that just gets returned out of this method.

Comment: Are you sure this line "$params[] = &$row[$field->name];" is not enforcing the existence of the $row variable?

Comment: I've confirmed that the line I posted in my previous comment is defining the variable. That was sneaky...